# How to pass checkbox id inside gridview from vb.net to javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have gridview in which i have checkbox on header and item templates. now i want to pass checkbox id from vb to javascript as follows.

```
  Protected Sub RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim headerchk As New CheckBox
        headerchk = DirectCast(gridview.HeaderRow.FindControl("chkheader"), CheckBox)
        Dim childchk As CheckBox = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("chkRow"), CheckBox)
        childchk.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:Selectchildcheckboxes('" + headerchk.ClientID + "')")  'but this line gives me error
    End If
 End Sub
```

javascript function would be,

```
function SelectheaderCheckboxes(headerchk) 
{
    if (headerchk.checked) 
    {
       //code
    }
}
```

i am getting "object reference not set to an instance of object" error.

Comment: what error your are getting ??

Comment: At run time, system will create different ID's for chkRow because in grid, system will replicate the same controls to number of rows times. So at run time chkRow ID will be different. What do you want to achieve? On selection of header check box, all checkbox should be selected? or anything different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead adding attributes on the server side , add the onclick event while designing and in your javascript add the following lines on the top.

These lines are for the headerCheckbox,

```
    var gvcheck = document.getElementById('<%=gridview.clientid %>');
    var chks = gvcheck.rows[0].getElementsByTagName("input");
    header = chks[`index of your checkbox`].id;
```

Design should be like this,

```
<asp:TemplateField>
 <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" onclick="javascript:Selectchildcheckboxes();" runat="server"/>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple. change like

```
childchk.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:Selectchildcheckboxes(" + headerchk.ClientID + ")")
```

because you have passed it as string. but you have to pass it as an id.